# I am confused about redux dispatch and how to call it inside the action. The tutorial I am following uses a method I don't understand

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Here is the following code for a tutorial I was following. This is the redux action:

```
import { SET_ALERT, REMOVE_ALERT } from './types';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
export const setAlert = (msg, alertType, timeout = 5000) => dispatch => {
  const id = uuidv4();
  dispatch({
    type: SET_ALERT,
    payload: { msg, alertType, id }
  });

  setTimeout(() => dispatch({ type: REMOVE_ALERT, payload: { id } }), timeout);
};
```

Here, dispatch is a parameter for the function nested in setAlert, but I am not sure how React recognizes this as the actual dispatch function and not some random variable, which is the first point of confusion. Next is where the action gets called:

```
const onSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (password !== password2) {
      setAlert('Passwords do not match', 'danger');
    }
};
```

When the action is being called in a component, setAlert only has one set of parenthesis. Doesn't that mean the dispatch code won't be run? The code works fine, but I don't know why. I'm just following this tutorial, and I am aware of other ways of dispatching, but I just don't understand this method. Maybe connect has something to do with it?

```
export default connect(
null,
{ setAlert }
)(Register);
```

Comment: "but I am not sure how React recognizes this as the actual dispatch function and not some random variable" it doesn't. "setAlert only has one set of parenthesis." You are correct that it doesn't seem to make any sense, the piece that you're missing is that it isn't the same setAlert. You are correct that the default export (which I'm assuming you alias to setAlert in the other module) wraps your alert function.

Comment: @JaredSmith How does dispatch work in this case if it's not the actual dispatch function? Does connect pass it in or something?

Comment: Correct, as far as I can see from what you've posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use redux connect then the `props.setAlert` is not the same as `import setAlert`. React-redux assumes that setAlert is a function and wraps it so it'll automatically dispatch. So `setAlert=params=>action using params` turns into `params=>dispatch(setAlert(params))`. This will become obvious if you don't name them the same:

```
import setAlert from 'actions';
... code
const onSubmit = async e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (password !== password2) {
    //setAlert('Passwords do not match', 'danger'); //will not work
    props.dispatchSetAlert('Passwords do not match', 'danger');//works
  }
};
...code
export default connect(null,{ dispatchSetAlert:setAlert })(Register);
```

I see that setAlert is a [thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk), when your action creator returns a function and you have redux-thunk as middleware then thunk will call that function with dispatch and getState as parameters. So that is where dispatch comes from in `setAlert = (params) => dispatch =>`